# Why do my Chilli plants have curling leaves, falling flowers, and ants?

Tags: diagnosis, insects, chili

My Chilli plant leaves are curling, the flowers are falling, and a lot of ants are traveling all the way to the place where the new leaves and flowers are shooting. I have tried burying banana peel pieces in the soil, but no go.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sachin! We can help you better with some more details. Would you please post some pictures of your plant, especially a close-up of the sick leaves, and the stalk with ants? Is it in a pot? Indoors or out?  Anything you can think of would be great! You can [edit] it right into your question. Also, if you press on the tag [tag:chili] you'll find a number of questions which might help you. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3):

Inspect the plant closely - its likely its infested with aphids (blackfly, greenfly, whitefly) of one sort or another, and ants like to collect the honeydew the aphids produce. The ants are a symptom of infestation. Spray with neem or a suitable insecticide for edible plants available where you are.

Comment: Definitely aphids. Weather and predators seem to keep them at bay when outdoors during the warm months, but as soon as I take them indoors to overwinter them, the aphids come and make the plants life miserable. If you don't want to use insecticide, showering the plants with high pressure water every once in a while will get rid of most of them and clean the honey dew.